# Setting Embedded Data Using If/Else Statement in JavaScript in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

In Qualtrics, I am trying to set two embedded data fields based on the answer to a yes or no question by using an if/else statement in JavaScript. I tried to come up with the correct code, but I am new to JS and what I've come up with (shown below) isn't working; the fields don't get populated.

I have created the embedded data fields in the beginning of the survey flow, so I don't think that's the issue.

```
 Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnPageLoad(function() {
   if("${q://QID14/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}"!="Yes") 
   {Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("Active_Duty_Yes", "X");
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("Active_Duty_No", "")}

  else if("${q://QID14/ChoiceGroup/SelectedChoices}"!="No") 
  {Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("Active_Duty_No", "X");
   Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("Active_Duty_Yes", "")};
       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your onload function name is wrong.  It should be addOnload instead of addOnPageLoad.

A couple of other suggestions:

1. Is is generally better to use use recodes instead of strings in
   logic (e.g., "${q://QID14/SelectedChoicesRecode}"!="1").  That way
   if you change the choice text the logic doesn't have to change.
2. It is generally better to give embedded data flags values of 1 and 0.